# Silently Installing pecl modules (e.g. pecl_http) Inside a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, pecl, silent-installer

I am attempting to install pecl_http inside a docker container. Currently my Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM fun:5000/apache-php:0.1.0

# Install dependencies
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
        php5-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev && \

    yes "\n" | pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6 && \
    echo "extension=http.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/http.ini && \
    cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ && \
    ln -s ../../mods-available/http.ini 20-http.ini && \
    ...
```

Initially I was simply using `pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6` in the docker file, and the container built successfully - without pecl_http installed.

If I attach to the container, I can install pecl_http with the interactive `pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6` by simply hitting enter after every prompt. I just learned about `yes`, and it seemed to fit my needs. Online searches indicated that many people have used it to perform unattended pecl installs, including pecl_http; however, when I attempt to use it in my docker container it fails with `configure: error: could not find magic.h`.

How can I perform a silent pecl_http install in Docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `pecl install` is asking you this question:

> whether to enable response content type guessing; specify libmagic directory [no] :

And `yes "\n"` isn't doing what you think it is - it's actually outputting:

```
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
```

So because you're saying `\n` in response to the above question, the installer thinks you're telling it to look in `\n` for `libmagic`, and of course it's failing because `\n` is nonsense.

`yes` has an implicit return after each command you tell it to output, so if you want to just have it hit return and use the defaults, use `yes ''`.

Working `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install dependencies
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install php5-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libevent-dev
RUN echo "extension=http.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/http.ini
RUN yes "" | pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
RUN cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/
RUN ln -s ../../mods-available/http.ini 20-http.ini
...
```

**Extra tip**: Don't be afraid to split your commands out into separate `RUN` statements to make full use of the docker cache.

Comment: Thanks for the Extra tip! I've been getting different feedback on how to split up RUN commands. Splitting them up is good as long as you install the same items a lot and in the same order. I've been focusing on specific Dockerfiles, so grouping related commands together has worked well for me.

Comment: I opened up a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25943274/118234) regarding splitting RUN statements, if you'd like to weigh in